# ValueError: Attempt to convert a value with an unsupported type to a Tensor. _DenseVariational.call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am facing some issues with my code.
The error I get is

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<keras.src.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x0000026CFA59FDD0>) with an unsupported type (<class 'keras.src.engine.sequential.Sequential'>) to a Tensor.

It comes from neg_log_likelihood

The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
    import tensorflow_probability as tfp
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    # Load the Iris dataset
    iris = load_iris()
    X = iris.data
    y = iris.target

    # Split the data into training and testing sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

    # Normalize the features
    mean, std = X_train.mean(axis=0), X_train.std(axis=0)
    X_train = (X_train - mean) / std
    X_test = (X_test - mean) / std

    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import kwarg_only

    kwargs = {'name': 'dense_layer'}

    # Compile the model
    bayesian_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss=neg_log_likelihood, metrics=['accuracy'])
   
    # Define the labels
    num_classes = 3
    labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=num_classes)


    tfp.layers.DenseReparameterization(
        units=10,
        activation=None,
        activity_regularizer=None,
        trainable=True,
        kernel_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.default_mean_field_normal_fn(),
        kernel_posterior_tensor_fn=(lambda d: d.sample()),
        kernel_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
        kernel_divergence_fn=(lambda q, p, ignore: tfp.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p)),
        bias_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.default_mean_field_normal_fn(is_singular=True),
        bias_posterior_tensor_fn=(lambda d: d.sample()),
        bias_prior_fn=None,
        bias_divergence_fn=(lambda q, p, ignore: tfp.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p)),
        **kwargs
    )

    # Create the Bayesian model
    input_shape = (X_train.shape[1])

    #Define the Bayesian Neural Network model using tf.keras
    def build_bayesian_model(input_shape):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=input_shape, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
            tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(3, activation="softmax")
        ])
        return model

    # Define a custom loss function
    logits = build_bayesian_model(X_train.shape[1:]) 
    y_pred = logits(X_test)
    neg_log_likelihood = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=X_test, logits=logits)
    kl = sum(model.losses)
    loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

    # Train the Bayesian Neural Network
    bayesian_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=1)
```

Has anybody an idea, how to solve this?
Any advise is much appreciated!
Thank you :)

I tried to change it to `neg_log_likelihood = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(3)`, but I run into another error code:

The tensor <tf.Tensor 'dense_reparameterization_4/divergence_kernel:0' shape=() dtype=float32> cannot    be accessed from here, because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=dense_reparameterization_4_scratch_graph, id=2194806230608), which is out of scope.

Also tried recoding:

```
 bayesian_model = build_bayesian_model(input_shape)
    neg_log_likelihood = tfp.layers.DenseReparameterization(2)  # Assuming 3 classes for Iris dataset

    bayesian_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=neg_log_likelihood, metrics=['accuracy'])

    num_classes = 3
    labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=num_classes)

    bayesian_model.fit(X_train, labels, epochs=1000, verbose=1)
```

But get a new errorcode here:
_DenseVariational.call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given